# Does this algorithm for permuting rows and columns of a matrix converge?

Tags: sorting, matrices, permutations

Given a binary matrix, define the magnitude of a row by reading off the numbers in it left to right and similarly for columns, reading the numbers going down. For instance, the row magnitude of the 1-st row of this matrix is 1001101, and for the 2-nd column it is 11.

1 0 0 1 1 0 1 
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 
0 1 1 0 0 1 0

I would like to sort a matrix by doing the following:

1. reorder rows so that rows are ordered in descending order according to their row magnitude
2. reorder columns so that columns are ordered in descending order according to their column magnitude
3. repeat 1 and 2 until rows and columns are in a correct order

For the matrix above this would go as follows:

sort by rows (step 1)
1 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 1

sort by columns (step 2)
1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 0

sort by rows (step 1)
1 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1

both columns and rows are in order, terminate procedure.

For the majority of matrices, performing steps 1 and 2 once won't be sufficient, since reordering columns will ruin the ordering of the rows. However, strangely enough it seems like 3 reorderings are sufficient to order matrices I've tried it on.

Despite not being able to find a counterexample, I struggle to see why this would be the case, and even more generally, what guarantees the algorithm won't get stuck in a cycle. Is there an existing name or more formal way to describe this algorithm and are there any proofs on its convergence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an $n \times m$ matrix $M$, define the potential function
$$
\Phi(M) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m 2^{n-1-i} 2^{m-1-j} M(i,j).
$$
If we write it as
$$
\Phi(M) = \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{n-1-i} \sum_{j=1}^m 2^{m-1-j} M(i,j)
$$
then it immediately follows that reordering rows either fixes $M$, or strictly increases $\Phi$. Similarly, reordering columns either fixes $M$ or strictly increases $\Phi$. Since there are only finitely many $n \times m$ matrices, it follows that your algorithm eventually converges.

It is definitely not the case that the process terminates after three steps. For example, here is a matrix which requires five steps:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
1&0&0&1 \\
0&0&1&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is a matrix in which the $(i,j)$'th entry depends only on $i+j$. Specifically, $M(i,j) = 1$ iff $i+j \in \{4,7,8\}$.

More generally, the $n \times n$ matrix $M$ in which $M(i,j)=1$ iff $i+j \in \{4,2n-1,2n\}$ requires $2n-3$ rounds, which is optimal for small values of $n$ (over *all* $n \times n$ matrices). Moreover, this is the unique choice over matrices of this form.

(To complete the picture, for $n = 3$ the unique optimal choice is $i + j \in \{4,6\}$ rather than $i+j \in \{4,5,6\}$, and for $n = 2$ the only choices are $i+j \in \{4\}$ and $i+j \in \{3,4\}$, which both correspond to two rounds.)

Comment: Exquisite! Where were those optimality and uniqueness proved?

Comment: It’s empirical results.